# error Message: Expected response code 220 but got an empty response" with exception "Swift_TransportException",

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

[image]I am following a tutorial to build an API using passport authentication on [enter link description here](https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f)
I have followed the part 1 and walking through the part 2 with **account confirmation and notifications** but eventually got a problem when I am testing on POSTMAN. The issue is, it does add to the database only that there is no mail sent with the error. I don't know of there is any configuration I need to do in .env or mail.php. As I tried to configure the email address, STMP and password. The same error is displayed again and most issues I have seen on here are quite different as most are pertaining to mail.php and .env which I have no idea as there is no such on the tutorial link and I even tried to alter the mail.php and .env, I ran **php artisan cache:clear**  but the same error is displayed.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class SignupActivate extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('/api/auth/signup/activate/'.$notifiable->activation_token);
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Confirm your account')
        ->line('Thanks for signup! Please before you begin, you must confirm your account.')
        ->action('Confirm Account', url($url))
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

I did also, two ways authentication
**Mail.php**

```php
<?php

return [

 
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'username@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Payne Curtis'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),


    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: After making any changes in `.env`, run `php artisan cache:clear` and php artisan config:cache` and try again.

Comment: Yes, I did all that

Comment: Have you tried 2-verification and ensure you configure the app password which will be used in the .env file?

Comment: Yes I did, 2-ways verification and app password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I can figure out your problem here. What you need to do is to make a strict setting to comply with the mail.php

```
return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'username@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Payne Curtis'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),


'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
];
```

Therefore change your .env to the following;

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=abdulkabirojulari@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=gjcltiocmmqoutfi
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls** is very essential and needs to be added to the .env file

Comment: Thank you so much... This saves my day. It works like a charm.